# Copy xml content from webpage and save to locally without special characters

Tags: python-3.x, xml, web-scraping

I'm trying to copy the content from a .xml webpage and copy locally to a test file using Python-selenium.
The webpage is generated based on earlier inputs(<//aep2/xml/trace/NIK243164_AI_14652732.xml>). I want to read the entire content of this xml, copy it locally and compare with an existing baseline Xml.

Here' a snipped of the .xml extension webpage:

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><IM415 xmlns="http://www.ros.ie/schemas/customs/IM415">   <Declaration>     <MsgType>H1</MsgType>     <DeclarationType_1_1>IM</DeclarationType_1_1>     <AdditionalDeclarationType_1_2>A</AdditionalDeclarationType_1_2>     <LRN_2_5>NIK243172_16K0O3</LRN_2_5>     <ValuationInformation>       <InvoiceCurrency_4_10>EUR</InvoiceCurrency_4_10>       <InvoiceAmount_4_11>5000</InvoiceAmount_4_11>       <InternalCurrency_4_12>EUR</InternalCurrency_4_12>     </ValuationInformation>     <GoodsInformation>       <GrossMass_6_5>300</GrossMass_6_5>       <TotalPackageNumber_6_18>15</TotalPackageNumber_6_18>     </GoodsInformation>     <TransportInformation>       <BorderTransportMode_7_4>3</BorderTransportMode_7_4>       <ActiveBorderTransportMeansNationality_7_15>IE</ActiveBorderTransportMeansNationality_7_15>     </TransportInformation>     <CustomsOffices>       <PresentationCustomsOffice_5_26>IEDUB100</PresentationCustomsOffice_5_26>       <CustomsOfficeLodgement>IEDUB100</CustomsOfficeLodgement>     </CustomsOffices>     <Parties>       <Declarant>         <Declarant_3_18 xmlns="">IE8218454B</Declarant_3_18>       </Declarant>       <Representative>         <Representative_3_20 xmlns="">IE8218454B</Representative_3_20>       </Representative>       <PersonPayingCustomsDuty_3_46>IE9726356R</PersonPayingCustomsDuty_3_46>     </Parties>     <PreferredPaymentMethod_4_8>E</PreferredPaymentMethod_4_8>   </Declaration>   <GoodsShipment>     <DocumentsAuthorisations>       <AdditionalInformation_2_2>         <AdditionalInformationCode xmlns="">00500</AdditionalInformationCode>       </AdditionalInformation_2_2>       <ProducedDocumentsWritingOff_2_03>         <DocumentType xmlns="">1D24</DocumentType>         <DocumentIdentifier xmlns="">202403211000</DocumentIdentifier>       </ProducedDocumentsWritingOff_2_03>       <ProducedDocumentsWritingOff_2_03>         <DocumentType xmlns="">1D94</DocumentType>         <DocumentIdentifier xmlns="">9214991</DocumentIdentifier>       </ProducedDocumentsWritingOff_2_03>       <ProducedDocumentsWritingOff_2_03>`

I've tried the below options, wherein each option has its own troubles:

1)

> with open('test.xml', 'w') as f:
> f.write(driver.page_source)

This extracts the info from the webpage but add html tags to start-end and also special characters to each tag. Is there a built-in function to automatically convert pagesource content to xml?

2)

> headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'}
> request = urllib.Request(url1, headers=headers)
> response = urllib.urlopen(request)
> print(response.status_code)
>
> if response.status_code == 200:
> with open('test.xml', 'wb') as f:
> shutil.copyfileobj(response.text, f)

This is unable to read from the Xml. I get a user-defined error returned 'there was an error generating the xml'. However, the xml is very much generated after my each script as I'm not running the cases headless at the moment.

3)

> urllib.request.urlretrieve(url1, "test.xml")

Similar issue as seen in 2)

Any help would be greatly appreciated around a solution that reads a webpage with .xml extension surpassing the user-defined error or perhaps just reading the pagesource in correct xml format.

Comment: Please read [ask] and make sure you have a [mre].